# Android Socket is closed error

Tags: java, android, sockets

I am developing an android application I am trying to connect with the server for username validation.. I am getting an error "java.net.socketException : Socket is closed" ... I am giving my code below if anyone can help pls help....

MainActivity

```
webserviceCallButton   = (Button)findViewById(R.id.login_Button);

        etUserName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextLogin);
        etPassword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword);
        webserviceResponse = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        webserviceCallButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                 webserviceResponse.setText("Requesting to server .....");

                    //Create Webservice class object
                    WebserviceCall com = new WebserviceCall(); 

                    // Initialize variables
                    String id  = "99999999999";
                    String password = "01233333";


                    //Call Webservice class method and pass values and get response
                    String aResponse = com.getmLogin("mLo",id,password);   

                    //Alert message to show webservice response
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), id+" id= "+aResponse+" hi", 
                       Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    Log.i("AndroidExampleOutput", "----"+aResponse);

                    webserviceResponse.setText("Response : "+aResponse);



            }
        });
    }
```

WebserviceCall

```
String namespace   = "https://xxxx.xxxx.com/";
    private String url = "https://xxxx.xxxx.xxxxxx.com/appservice/d_service.asmx";

    String SOAP_ACTION = "https://xxxxx.com/mLo";
    SoapObject request = null, objMessages = null;
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope;
    AndroidHttpTransport androidHttpTransport;

    WebserviceCall() {
    }


    /**
     * Set Envelope
     */
    protected void SetEnvelope() {

        try {

            // Creating SOAP envelope           
            envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

            //You can comment that line if your web service is not .NET one.
            envelope.dotNet = true;

            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
            androidHttpTransport = new AndroidHttpTransport(url);
            androidHttpTransport.debug = true;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Soap Exception---->>>" + e.toString());    
        }
    }

    // MethodName variable is define for which webservice function  will call
    public String getmLogin(String mLo, String customerid,
            String customername) 
      {

        try {

            //SOAP_ACTION = namespace + MethodName;
            //SOAP_ACTION = namespace + MethodName;

            //Adding values to request object
            request = new SoapObject(namespace, mLo);


            //Adding String value to request object
            request.addProperty("customerid", "" + customerid);
            request.addProperty("customername", "" + customername);

            SetEnvelope();

            try {

                //SOAP calling webservice
                androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

                //Got Webservice response
                String result = envelope.getResponse().toString();

                return result;

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                return e.toString();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            return e.toString();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Post the stack trace, and if it emanates from code you haven't posted yet, post that as well.

Answer (score 2):

This exception means you have closed the socket and tried to use it again.

If you close the input or output stream it will automatically close the other stream, and the Socket.

Just close down when you are finished completley

Comment: @Jocheved i can't see a call to .close() in your snippet, do you have a call elsewhere? i am at work so can't commit fully.

Comment: No this is my full code...http://androidexample.com/Dot_Net_Webservice_Call_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=100&aaid=122

Comment: @Jocheved Links to code are not acceptable. You need to post a minimal piece of code that exhibts the problem, *in your question.*

Comment: The  code I gave here is my full code.. but I couldn't able to find out  any error in that... but... the error I am getting is socket closed ...